# Hacer pirámide de asteriscos apuntando a la izquierda en Java

Tags: java, consola, lógica

Encontré en internet como hacerla apuntando a la derecha que es con el siguiente Código:

```
System.out.println();
for(int altura = 1; altura<=(numFilas/2); altura++){
    //Espacios en blanco
    for(int asteriscos = 0; asteriscos<altura; asteriscos++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for(int altura = (numFilas/2)+1; altura>0; altura--){
    //Espacios en blanco
    for(int asteriscos = 0; asteriscos<altura; asteriscos++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Pero no se como hacer que apunte a la izquierda, si pudieran poner explicación seria mucho mejor porque quiero aprender bien, sino solo con el código basta, yo lo comprenderé luego.

Quiero lograr algo asi pero hacia el otro lado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si bien tienes codigo, esta es una de las pocas ocasiones en las que es buena idea tener una imagen de referencia de lo que quisieras lograr, por ejemplo poner una imagen ejemplo de la piramide resultado, porque dices apuntando a la izquierda... pero pues hay otras cosas a tener en cuenta segun esta premisa...

Comment: Para dejar un espacio en blanco, haz *System.out.print(" ")*

Comment: Hay un problema... me he dado cuenta de algo, los triangulos creados con numeros pares son imposible que existan (o por lo menos que existan y que tengan la misma distancia al centro que sus extremos), por lo que si se usa un numero par habrá siempre un lado que no podrá ser llenado acorde la estructura del triangulo (quedará descuadrado), mientras que usando numeros impares el triangulo es plausible y puede existir sin llegar a deformarse o a no poder completarse con ambos extremos midiendo lo mismo, me he dado cuenta de esto haciendo bastantes pruebas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve haciendo ciertas pruebas y me di cuenta de que enrealidad no es posible tener un triangulo con **altura par** (lo intente primero en el codigo y luego lo intente plasmar en un bloc de notas), el resultado fue que uno de los lados si o si iba a quedar desigual o truncado por un asterisco, asterisco el cuál según como funciona la impresión hace imposible el hecho de que triangulos con **altura par** existan sin que uno de sus lados queden truncados.

Ahora bien, he modificado tu ejemplo y creado el siguiente ejemplo:

```
final int altura = 11;
final int mitterPoint = Math.round(altura / 2) + 1;
String asterisks = " ".repeat(mitterPoint);

for(int i = 0; i < altura; i++){
    if((i + 1) <= mitterPoint){
        asterisks = asterisks.substring(1, asterisks.length());
        asterisks += "*";
    }else{
        asterisks = " ".repeat((i + 1) - mitterPoint) + asterisks.substring((i + 1) - mitterPoint, asterisks.length());
    }
    System.out.println(asterisks);
}
```

Este código funcionara bien para imprimir cualquier triangulo que tenga una altura mayor o igual a `3` y ademas que su altura **sea impar**, por supuesto fallará para aquellos triángulos cuya altura sea par según lo dicho anteriormente.

Explicando un poco el nuevo código, primero tenemos:

```
System.out.println();
```

Que es una versión diferente de `System.out.print()` que usabas en tu código, la diferencia es que `System.out.println()` imprime por lineas (crea un salto de linea al final), mientras que `System.out.print()` no imprime por lineas (no añade un salto de linea al final), por lo cuál considere conveniente para tu problema usar `System.out.println()` en vez de `System.out.print()`.

Ahora bien, aqui creamos `3` variables, la `altura` del triangulo, `mitterPoint` que se refiere a la altura en la cuál el triangulo alcanza 'su punto mas alto', y `asterisks` que almacena un `string` que contiene la cantidad de asteriscos usados hasta ese momento en el ciclo junto con los espacios.

```
final int altura = 11;
final int mitterPoint = Math.round(altura / 2) + 1;
String asterisks = " ".repeat(mitterPoint);
```

creamos el ciclo para iterar desde el inicio del triangulo, hasta su altura:

```
for(int i = 0; i < altura; i++){
   ...
}
```

Si la `pocisión actual del ciclo + 1` (para comenzar desde el 1 y no desde el 0) es **menor o igual** al pico del triangulo, entonces quitamos un espacio de entre los que teniamos en `asterisks` y le añadimos al final un asterisco:

```
if((i + 1) <= mitterPoint){
   asterisks = asterisks.substring(1, asterisks.length());
   asterisks += "*";
}
```

En caso contrario añadimos dependiendo del ciclo de a uno, dos, 3 o mas espacios por iteración (partiendo desde la altura donde se encuentra el pico) (`mitterPoint`), luego a esto le concatenamos la cantidad de asteriscos faltantes para llegar hasta la parte mas derecha del triangulo (la base):

```
else{
   asterisks = " ".repeat((i + 1) - mitterPoint) + asterisks.substring((i + 1) - mitterPoint, asterisks.length());
}
```

Por ultimo imprimimos los asteriscos en cada iteración:

```
System.out.println(asterisks);
```

Sobre la duda de si hay alguna manera de que también funcione para triángulos con altura par, **no la hay** puesto que hay que considerar que no puedes imprimir un asterisco en una linea intermedia... (**no existen lineas intermedias, solo lineas**), al intentar escribir un triangulo de esa manera tendrás es un impedimento de lineas.

Sin embargo si en vez de "escribir" un triangulo par lo intentaras dibujar, usando asteriscos (por ejemplo usando `Graphics2D` de `java`), si que es posible crear triángulos con altura par sin que se desfasen, corten o se vean distorsionados, puesto que ya no **escribirías** por lineas, si no que **dibujarias** por pixeles.

Comment: Nota: me asegure de calcular bien esto, por lo que, no el triangulo ejemplo mostrado en tu codigo no tiene altura 10 (pese a que escribiste que querias 10 filas en tu codigo), conte las filas y enrealidad tiene altura 11, por esta razón el triangulo no esta truncado ni tampoco tiene ese impedimento de la linea intermedia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por eso, me fue de mucha ayuda, solo que lo que quiero es que el triangulo se imprima hacia el otro lado, apuntando a la izquierda

Comment: Eso es lo que no tengo ni la mas minima idea de como hacer

Comment: Ah entiendo... supongo que editare la respuesta para que apunte al otro lado, en breves  la edito, pense que era hacia el lado de tu demo.

Comment: Listo, respuesta modificada, ahora debe imprimirlos de derecha a izquierda.

Comment: Perfecto, muchisimas gracias, me funciono de 10 y entendi

Answer (score 0):

Para pirámides sentido izquierdo o derecho, el renglón medio siempre será ceiling(filas/2) + modulo(filas+1, 2). Si filas es 10 entonces tu renglón medio es: ceiling(10/2) + modulo(10+1,2) => ceiling(5) + modulo(11,2) => 5 + 1 => 6. Si filas es 9 entonces tu renglón medio es: ceiling(9/2) + modulo(9+1,2) => ceiling(4.5) + modulo(10,2) => 5 + 0 => 5. La longitud de la cadena para cada renglón es igual al renglón, por lo tanto la cadena MAXIMA es la del renglón central. Las cadenas para pirámides sentido derecho son sólo del símbolo de relleno que se use (*), las cadenas para pirámides sentido son cadenas de espacios de longitud MAXIMA - renglón, concatenadas con cadenas del símbolo * de longitud renglón.

Comment: Pero como lo paso en codigo?

Comment: Por favor revisa [answer], y edita tu respuesta, saludos.